# How to ensure data integrity in Hyperledger Fabric when someone intentionally changes data in couchdb directly

Tags: rest, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, integrity

I'm currently having 2 organizations inside my Hyperledger Fabric, and I'm accessing both of the organizations using generated API by `composer-rest-server`.

According to my understanding, `Hyperledger Fabric` keeps its states inside `couchdb` and keeping its `ledger` in every organizations thus providing integrity.

The problem is let's say, when I try to change some sort of data directly in `couchdb`using `cURL` method on `org2`, it shows lack of data integrity. for example :

This Data

> "_id":"\u0000Asset:org.hospital.record.DataMedis\u0000001\u0000","_rev":"2-e590415fbc6092dc3ddc0b5271bab524","$class":"org.hospital.record.DataMedis","$registryId":"org.hospital.record.DataMedis","$registryType":"Asset","alasanMasuk":"string","alasanPulang":"string","anamnesis":"string","diagnosaPrimer":"**DBD Tingkat I**","diagnosaSekunder":"string","dokter":"resource:org.hospital.record.Dokter#001","idRekMedis":"001","kondisiSaatPulang":"string","noRekMedis":"000001","pasien":"resource:org.hospital.record.Pasien#001","pemeriksaanFisik":"string","prognosaPenyakit":"string","rencanaTindakLanjut":"string","riwayatAlergi":"string","rujukan":"string","terapiDiRs":"string","tglKeluar":"string","tglMasuk":"string","tindakan":"string","~version":"\u0000CgMBDQA="

Changing the diagnosis into this Data

> "_id":"\u0000Asset:org.hospital.record.DataMedis\u0000001\u0000","_rev":"2-e590415fbc6092dc3ddc0b5271bab524","$class":"org.hospital.record.DataMedis","$registryId":"org.hospital.record.DataMedis","$registryType":"Asset","alasanMasuk":"string","alasanPulang":"string","anamnesis":"string","diagnosaPrimer":"**Influenza**","diagnosaSekunder":"string","dokter":"resource:org.hospital.record.Dokter#001","idRekMedis":"001","kondisiSaatPulang":"string","noRekMedis":"000001","pasien":"resource:org.hospital.record.Pasien#001","pemeriksaanFisik":"string","prognosaPenyakit":"string","rencanaTindakLanjut":"string","riwayatAlergi":"string","rujukan":"string","terapiDiRs":"string","tglKeluar":"string","tglMasuk":"string","tindakan":"string","~version":"\u0000CgMBDQA="

The result is the data between `org1` and `org2` isn't identical anymore. Here's the result using `GET` method from the `composer-rest-server` API:

[image]

[image]

Is there any way I can maintain its data integrity when someone attacking directly to my `couchdb`? or is there any configuration should I make to `composer-rest-server`?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state database is not the source of truth; the actual ledger is.  The state database is really a persistent cache for the last known value of each key.

As alluded to by @risabh, endorsement policies are used to determine updates to state.  So the next time there is a transaction which changes that state, as long as the endorsement policy is satisfied the "modified" key's latest value will be overwritten by the new value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Correct me if I'm wrong, as far as I know, composer-rest-server shows the data from the state database. So is it possible to realize data differences when someone modified the state database?

Comment: You'd actually need to do a "strong" read .... meaning making calls to multiple peers to retrieve the data.  I do not recall whether or not the composer-rest-server ended up adding the ability to query multiple peers on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Cant comment so adding here.

When you would try to add data for the same key again trough an invoke txn there would be an endorsement failure message from the peer for which the data is changed.This shows there is a miss match in read write set and the data is tampered.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a little bit confused. You mean when I try to add data for the same key it will show me an error because the data with "that key"  had already added?

Comment: Data in the ledger is stored as a key value pair. You have changed a state data.it would be associated to a key. Now assume ur endorsement policy is set to ORGa and ORGb.When you try to update the data which you have changed,the endorsing peers would simulate the chaincode execution and they would idealy send the signed proposal back to the client if everything is fine but you have changed the state data for one of the org so the read write sets of both the endorsing peers wont match and hence it would lead to endorsement failure.